# DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain gives {"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, websocket, sdk

I am using AWS WebSocket to push notifications. for that, I'm trying to invoke the below code block.

```
public ApiGatewayResponse execute(HttpMethodName method, String resourcePath, InputStream content){
    final ExecutionContext executionContext = createExecutionContext();
    DefaultRequest request = prepareRequest(method,resourcePath,content);
    return this.client.execute(request, responseHandler, errorResponseHandler, executionContext).getAwsResponse();
}
```

I'm using AWSStaticCredentialsProvider to generate the credential and add those details to the executionContext in the above method. AWSStaticCredentialsProvider using like below

```
this.credentials = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
```

so from this approach, I was able to push content into the connected channels. But I have to use a static access key and secret key from a config file. I wanted to remove those details from the config file and exclude this AWSStaticCredentialsProvider part. For that, I'm trying to use DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain. When I generate the credential from DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain and add them to the executionContext it gives  {"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}. Maybe I have not correctly implemented this scenario. Does anyone know how do we use DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain for this kind of scenario?